# One to many relationship and Other object relation

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am learning hibernate. It may be a basic question, I am not able to figure out the issue,

I am having an object called **Customer**, It will have a relationship with **address** object **(one-to-one relation)** and **Tickets** object **(one-to-many relation)**. **[Each customer can have many tickets]**. And **Each ticket will have a payment object** (**One-to-one relation**). I specified the relation in hibernate annotation.

I am getting the below error when executing the test,

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.test.model.Tickets.payment, referenced property unknown: com.test.model.Payment.tickets
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

If I remove the **Payment object** and their reference in java as well as in **hibernate.cfg.xml**, It **works fine** with three objects **(Customer, Address, and Tickets)**. If add a Payment object for the customer , It is not working. Where am i wrong in this code ?

My objects,
Customer :
[image]

Address :

[image]

Tickets :

[image]

Payment :

[image]

Test program is :

[image]

Hibernate Configuration is :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the error message, there is no property named `tickets` in `Payment`. Instead of it there is property named `ticket` (singular). Following should be used:

```
mappedBy="ticket"
```

Comment: Your answer fixed that issue, Now i am facing different issue like, Can you guide me ? I getting different kind of issue, I placed the exception over here, http://pastebin.com/Z2LPYR9E