# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:521)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate, I just had some doubts and clarified in this website ([One to many relationship and Other object relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496496/one-to-many-relationship-and-other-object-relation/16496734#comment23847995_16496734)).

[image]

For the same application i am facing different issue. the exception is, what i am missing in this app.

```
Hibernate: insert into TestDB.customer (name, registrationDate) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TestDB.tickets (accessories, comments, uid, problem, problemFiledDate, repairTye, status, statusChangedDate) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:521)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3867)
    at org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator.generate(ForeignGenerator.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at com.test.CustomerRunWithTicketsWithPay.saveCustomer(CustomerRunWithTicketsWithPay.java:83)
    at com.test.CustomerRunWithTicketsWithPay.main(CustomerRunWithTicketsWithPay.java:22)
```

My Application code is

**My objects, Customer :**

[image]

**Address :**

[image]

**Tickets :**

[image]

**Payment :**

[image]

**Test program is :**

[image]

**My Hibernate Configuration is :**

[image]

Comment: My first guess would be that you're accessing a lazily-initialized property outside of a transaction (meaning it hasn't been initialized and it's null), or that you're trying to persist an uninitialized property in an object, and it's trying to get the value of that property - which is accessing some method on a null object, resulting in this exception.  Can we see the objects in question and your DAO/service layer(s)?

Comment: I had some other queries on the same object. My application details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496496/one-to-many-relationship-and-other-object-relation/16496734?noredirect=1#16496734

Comment: *It would also be nice to see the lines from this custom class you wrote,* **at com.test.CustomerRunWithTicketsWithPay.saveCustomer(CustomerRunWithTicketsWithPay.java:83)
at com.test.CustomerRunWithTicketsWithPay.main(CustomerRunWithTicketsWithPay.java:22)** but i fear it can be one of the variables for input into the DB query is null not merely from a property or uninstantiated or defective persistant object. Again too, you are using the ?,?,? transaction query "template syntax" which is also a little tricky to keep matched to the initial query template base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer, The mistake is on the below line of **Payment POJO**.

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "tickets"))
```

Here I specified like **value = "tickets"** which is invalid in this mapping. I have to specify like **value = "ticket"**. This fixed it.

Comment: Wht you had to make it TICKET?